# Laravel Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.3

Im getting an error when trying to launch a Laravel App .

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class log does not exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:735
```

I have checked the .env file for spaces and found none. I also replaced each file in the config folder in a attempt to find out which one would throw the error. I also tried doing a dump just the mentioned line

```
dump($concrete, debug_backtrace());
```

I have also tried running composer dump-autoload and composer dump-autoload -o which promted me to put the composer.json file into the config directory
Then when ran again threw the error stating "Could not scan for classes inside database which does not appear to be a file nor a folder".

How can a isolate and sort this issue out ?

Comment: Are you using laravel's Log facade? This looks like you're trying to utilise a class without declaring it with a `use` statement first.

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
$  composer dump-autoload -o
```

and try again